# FTP only changed files in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

An MSBuild project copies its output to a directory on a server. Each day, only a few files change and most have an older creation date.
I can FTP this to a remote server with MSBuild tasks.  But how can I do this FTP and only copy the few files that have changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you'll need something that will manage the sync for you - that is that will keep track of what file is where and update accordingly.

We have used [FTPSync](http://www.cyberkiko.com/page/FTPSync.aspx) to do the file sync bit very tidly for a number of sites.

From MSBuild you can call an external program - so putting the two together will probably work providing your are consistently synching from the same location (otherwise its going to be more interesting!)