# Delete folders from FTP using MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, ftp, msbuild-task

How is it possible to delete recursively folders from FTP using MSBuild task or script?

Comment: if you have a way to do that from the command-line, you can do it in msbuild, too.

Answer (score 0):

You might try out [FTPSync](http://www.cyberkiko.com/page/FTPSync.aspx) as recommended in the answer to [FTP only changed files in MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881474/ftp-only-changed-files-in-msbuild).

If you can mount the FTP site to your build environment, you can do a recursive delete using the [Well-known Item Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313%28VS.80%29.aspx) %(RecursiveDir) property. You can also create a target to do that like [this example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikhilsi/archive/2010/05/10/tfs-build-post-build-cleanup-recursively-delete-wildcard-files-using-msbuild-proj.aspx).